# PayPal Integration - Currency Issue

Tags: java, android

If I use USD currency in my application it works fine and transaction also completed in environment as ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX, but if I use other currencies, like Japanese yen (JPY), Russian ruble(RUB)etc., before setting the currency in my application, added currency in developer option also but it wasn't able to complete the transaction. It stayed at 'pending'.

**Working fine code:**

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), **"USD",** "Simplified Coding Fee",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

**Not Working**

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), **"EUR",** "Coding Fee",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

I have attached sandbox details image for ref.

**PayPal integration not in Indian currency**

Also, how do I enable the Indian Currency in PayPal currency list?

[Sandbox details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PWp3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. INR is still not one of the listed and available currency. For Indian to Indian account, the cross-border currency is used to accept payment.

Read here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/